# How to access the transaction of the current context while extending QueryBuilder class in Knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-builder, knex.js, objection.js

Im trying to extend the `QueryBuilder` of Knex.js. I want to modify the `delete()` method in order to delete the child elements of my Objection.js Model. Current code works well, but I want to support transactions in the new method:

```
class CustomQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder {
  // Override delete method
  delete() {
    return super.select('*').first().runAfter(async (old, builder) => {
      // Some extra logic here, being able to access old entry
      return await old.query().nativeDelete() // original delete
    })
  }

  nativeDelete() {
    return super.delete()
  }
}
```

Where is the transaction of current context? Is it accesible?

Note: I cannot pass it as a param in `delete(trx)` function, since `delete()` could be called from other methods without passing it explicitly as a param

Answer (score 0):

The current transaction of the QueryBuilder is accesible trough `builder.context()`:

```
class CustomQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder {
  // Override delete method
  delete() {
    return super.select('*').eager('reference').runAfter(async (olds, builder) => {
      return await Promise.all(olds.map(old => old.$query(builder.context().transaction).mergeContext(builder.context()).nativeDelete()))
    })
  }

  nativeDelete() {
    return super.delete()
  }
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all` like that may cause you problems and since all the queries are going through the same transaction you wont get any parallelism benefits from there either. `Promise.all` will reject / throw an error when first of the queries fail, so your `delete()` method throws an error, but other promises you initialized in `olds.map` are still executing... so better would be to use normal for (let old of olds) loop and await every query separately.

Comment: This was on the way to production... I will check it and fix this response. Thanks for your comment @MikaelLepistö